# Can't sent post (I am using Strapi)

Tags: post, http-status-code-404, strapi

I am using Strapi. I am trying to send a post to my API. With the same URL, I don't have any problem to use GET.

I tested my API with Postman and I get this error :

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Missing \"data\" payload in the request body",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Emilie. You haven't received any answers because your question doesn't include the details of your POST request. Please update your question with more information (headers, body, etc) and we may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Just add data to it like this : ----

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "NewClient",
        "email": "firstcontact@christii.com",
        "country": null,
        "phone_no": "9815456467765",
        "message": "Hey"
    }
}
```